# ASP.NET Where can I write to without modifying permissions?

Tags: asp.net, permissions

Where can I write to without modifying site permissions? I need to store a value on the server that will remain when all sessions have closed and can be re-read when a new session is started. I need to make sure that no site permissions need to be changed so the location can be written to by anonymous users and any authenticated user.

Does such a place exist?

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 1):

Store the value in the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx).  Make sure to mark it as not removable with a sufficiently long expiration time.  The value needs to persist even when the application is restarted, then store it in a database (perhaps in App_Data).

Answer (score 0):

I think the App_Data folder is set up with permissions for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Or application variables if you aren't load balancing and it doesn't need to persist between restarts ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about saving your session variables in a sql database.  This will allow iis to restart and your sessions will still be alive.

http://idunno.org/articles/277.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could also use a `public static` field or if the value doesn't change a `public static readonly` field internally in the application directly. If you update the value make sure to do locking correctly on updates.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else said, depends on if you have a database available or if volatile stores like Profile, session, viewstate or cache will do.

If you are looking for a place to write files to, then consider Isolated Storage, which is like a sandboxed filesystem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx